# MySQL: unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, left-join

When I run this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `page` `p` LEFT JOIN `lang` `l`
ON `p.id`=`l.pageID` 
WHERE `p.textID`='home' 
    AND `l.language`='EN'
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown column 'p.textID' in 'where clause'
```

even though I'm sure that there is a column called `textID` in the table `page`.

The `lang` table has the following columns: `id`, `pageID`, `navTitle`, `title`, `content`, `language`.
The `page` table has the following columns: `id`, `textID`, `nav`.

what could cause this error?

Comment: Try \`p\`.\`textID\` or remove apostrophes at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to wrap your identifiers in backticks, you need to do it separately for table and column names.

So you need, for example,

```
 `p`.`textID`
```

rather than

```
 `p.textID`
```

The same applies to the other identifiers in your query.

Comment: Found this answer useful +1 for `backticks` :o)

Answer (score 3):

Not

```
`p.textID`
```

but

```
`p`.`textID`
```

and not

```
`l.language`
```

but

```
`l`.`language`
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it should for example be:

```
`p`.`id`
```

Instead of

```
`p.id`
```

and so on...